# My RSS feed is not working

Tags: feed

I run my website on wordpress 4.1 and my website feed is not working. Feed page shows this error message.

(This page contains the following errors:

error on line 399 at column 105: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0x1F 0x6F 0x72 0x64
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.)

I tried it using different theme but still showing same error. Any idea how can I fix this.

Here is the feed addresses: http://feeds.feedburner.com/WeBuildDesign
http://webuilddesign.com/feed

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it was caused by a plugin please disable all plugins and try again.

If it doesn't help try removing following line from "180 power words for writing emotional headlines:"

"So it is always a good idea to make emotional headlines for your content."

Comment: At first that thought you were joking when you told me to remove that line. But then I actually did that and it worked. How did you know it will work? Thanks

Comment: Glad to here that! The message says there is an invalid character in that sentence!